# Object Intercept in Space question

Tags: calculus, approximation, celestial-mechanics

I have a formula, which given a time $t$, returns the $x$ and $y$ position of a planet, essentially it fakes a planet orbiting a star.

I have a ship that is stationary with respect to the planet, starting at an arbitrary location, it thrusts at a constant rate, leading to constant acceleration, with no friction, or no gravitational forces.

> I want to determine what vector the ship should thrust at, and for how long (I expect $t/2$) before decelerating in order to reach the destination planet at the exact time the planet arrives at that location.

Initially I tried to determine how long it would take $t_1$ to arrive at the planet, at it's current location $(x_1, y_1)$.  Then I determine how long it would take $t_2$, to arrive at the planet, at it's location after $t_1$ time has passed $(x_2, y_2)$.  Then I iterated over this over and over again until $t_n$ was very close to $t_{n+1}$ and used $(x_n, y_n)$ as the target location, which had a ton of flaws and was very computationally expensive.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Hi and welcome to the M.SE. If you want to produce beautiful and beautifully formatted mathematical text for your questions and answer, please have a look [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: Does stationary to the planet mean in a circular orbit?  No gravity implies the planet has zero mass?  You'll need to thrust forward in the direction of the orbit until planetary escape.  If the planet is ethereal,  thus massless, the craft  has escaped planetary capture.

Comment: Stationary means stationary with respect to the the point the planet is orbitting around, in most cases, the single star in the system.  Initially the ship will be on the location of the star the planet is orbitting, without any velocity.

The planet's mass is not considered in its motion, and it doesn't have an impact on the ship (due to no gravity), for the purposes of motion, we can consider it massless.

Comment: As an example.
Planet at (0, 10), ship at (0,0).  The ship takes 10 seconds given it's acceleration rate, to travel to (0, 10) from (0,0).  But after 10 seconds, the planet will be at (10, 0).   If instead the ship had travelled to (10, 0), it would have arrived at the planet at the exact time the planet arrived there.  I'd like to know how to determine the (x,y) I should head towards, in order to arrive at the same point the planet arrives there based on my current position, acceleration, and the motion of the planet (which varies based only on Time that's passed).

Comment: Let me paraphrase your question to see if I understand your setting correctly. **Find a practical if not optimal trajectory of the ship**: On the Euclidean 2-dim plane, a massless planet is orbiting the origin circularly with known constant speed and known radius. The ship starts at an arbitrary point and can perform acceleration in any direction but only in constant magnitude. The landing of the ship on the planet means not only their position vectors coincide but also their **velocity vectors** must be the same (so that the ship is motionless relative to the planet).